# how to get rid of the unassigned pointer in this case?

Tags: recursion, prolog

Here are the facts I use :

```
edge(route(fra), route(tog), walk).
edge(route(fra), route(105), walk).
edge(route(tog), route(togc), bus).
edge(route(togc), route(sub), walk).
edge(route(sub), route(ag), metro).
edge(route(ag), route(n), metro).
edge(route(n), route(a), metro).
edge(route(a), route(r), metro).
edge(route(re), route(m), metro).
edge(route(m), route(v), walk).
edge(route(105), route(t), bus).
edge(route(t), route(vi), metro).
edge(route(vi), route(m), metro).
edge(route(t), route(3), walk).
edge(route(3), route(m), bus).
```

And the predicates :

```
seek(route(v), _).
seek(route(R1), [[R2, How]|Res]) :-
    edge(route(R1), route(R2), How),
    seek(route(R2),Res).
```

when I ask the query `?- seek(route(fra), X).`

It should return `R2` and `How` in a list, but `Res` in this case remains unassigned... I don't know how can I get around that to make that query only return a list of lists containing `R2`. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion anchor (the first clause of your `seek/2` predicate) always returns a variable as second argument. Instead, it should return an empty list.